# Why is do while loop creating/overwriting 2 separate arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code that is overwriting my array on the second pass through of the while loop.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'constants/constants.php';

use net\authorize\api\contract\v1 as AnetAPI;
use net\authorize\api\controller as AnetController;

require('includes/application_top.php');


define("AUTHORIZENET_LOG_FILE", "phplog");


function getUnsettledTransactionList()
{


//get orders that are in the exp status
    $orders_pending_query = tep_db_query("select orders_id as invoice_number from " . TABLE_ORDERS . " where orders_status = '14' order by invoice_number");

    $orders_pending = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($orders_pending_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $orders_pending[] = $row;
    }

    /* Create a merchantAuthenticationType object with authentication details
       retrieved from the constants file */
    $merchantAuthentication = new AnetAPI\MerchantAuthenticationType();
    $merchantAuthentication->setName(\SampleCodeConstants::MERCHANT_LOGIN_ID);
    $merchantAuthentication->setTransactionKey(\SampleCodeConstants::MERCHANT_TRANSACTION_KEY);

    // Set the transaction's refId
    $refId = 'ref' . time();

    $pagenum = 1;
    do {
        $request = new AnetAPI\GetUnsettledTransactionListRequest();
        $request->setMerchantAuthentication($merchantAuthentication);


        $paging = new AnetAPI\PagingType;
        $paging->setLimit("1000");

        $paging->setOffset($pagenum);
        $request->setPaging($paging);


        $controller = new AnetController\GetUnsettledTransactionListController($request);

        $response = $controller->executeWithApiResponse(\net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::PRODUCTION);
        $transactionArray = array();
        $resulttrans = array();
        if (($response != null) && ($response->getMessages()->getResultCode() == "Ok")) {
            if (null != $response->getTransactions()) {


                foreach ($response->getTransactions() as $tx) {
                    $transactionArray[] = array(
                        'transaction_id' => $tx->getTransId(),
                        'invoice_number' => $tx->getInvoiceNumber()
                    );


                    // echo "TransactionID: " . $tx->getTransId() . "order ID:" . $tx->getInvoiceNumber() . "Amount:" . $tx->getSettleAmount() . "<br/>";
                }


           
                $invoiceNumbers = array_column($orders_pending, "invoice_number");
                $result = array_filter($transactionArray, function ($x) use ($invoiceNumbers) {
                    return in_array($x["invoice_number"], $invoiceNumbers);
                });
                $resulttrans = array_column($result, "transaction_id");
                 



            } else {
                echo "No unsettled transactions for the merchant." . "\n";
            }
        } else {
            echo "ERROR :  Invalid response\n";
            $errorMessages = $response->getMessages()->getMessage();
            echo "Response : " . $errorMessages[0]->getCode() . "  " . $errorMessages[0]->getText() . "\n";
        }





        $numResults = (int) $response->getTotalNumInResultSet();

        $pagenum++;
        print_r($resulttrans);
      
    } while ($numResults === 1000);


   
    return $resulttrans;

}

getUnsettledTransactionList();


?>
```

the  print_r($resulttrans); is actually printing 2 separate arrays, instead of my desired 1 array.

If I move the print_r($resulttrans) to after the while loop, I am only seeing the second array, meaning the first array was overwritten. I am not seeing where this is happening though as to me it seems like all results should be added onto the array.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is supposed to work as you described because you are reassigning the array variable in your loop like this

```
$resulttrans = array_column($result, "transaction_id");
```

If you need to get all the resulting values in the same array you need to append it to the array. you can do that by merging the new result into your array variable like this

```
$resulttrans = array_merge($resulttrans, array_column($result, "transaction_id"));
```